# How to convert radiation pattern measurements into CST ffs format

Tags: rf, antenna

I'm trying to import the measured radiation pattern of an antenna in CST FFS (far field source) format. The problem I'm facing is that my measurements are in gain (magnitude/phase) form, and the FFS file format has values in \$\text{Re}(E_\theta)\$, \$\text{Im}(E_\theta)\$, \$\text{Re}(E_\phi)\$ and \$\text{Im}(E_\phi)\$ format.

Is there any formula that would help me convert gain values to \$E_\theta\$ and \$E_\phi\$ form?

Comment: What research have you done before asking? Have you tried googling "convert radiation pattern to far field sources"? There appear to be several calculators etc out there.

Comment: Yes I have, there are no particular calculators for converting the value of measured gain to E_theta and E_phi as required in the ffs format. I replaced the values of E_theta in an ffs file by converting magnitude/phase to real/imaginary form. I then used the same values for E_phi assuming CP. The pattern obtained by importing the edited ffs source file to CST seems to be near that of the original measurement, but the gain values are changed. For example, a measured value of -40 dB shows to be around -90 dB. The relation between measured gain and ffs format required E_theta/phi is unclear.

Comment: Matlab.  We use it for post-processing and detailed analysis of our near field antenna measurements.

Comment: Who makes your antenna measurement system, or is in home grown?  Companies like NSI have FAEs and some basic post-processing software available for their users.

Comment: @SteveSh can you please guide through the process

Comment: @SteveSh NSI antenna measurement system is used, but gives out pattern data in terms of gain and phase, whereas ffs format uses E_phi and E_theta values

Comment: @AETECH E_phi and E_theta are not directly related to your gain and phase values, they are for two different polarizations.  You gain and phase map more closely to the real and imaginary parts of a single polarization.  Do you know the polarization of your measurements?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome - Sounds like OP is getting the measurements for two orthogonal polarizations, phi & theta, from his equipment.  How that's accomplished is a guess.

Comment: I have the gain/phase measurements of both co and x polarizations, I think I will have to use both these polarizations to construct E_theta and E_phi values. Are you aware of any conversion formulae?